# Can I save an audio buffer offline to reuse later?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm using the Web Audio API to play audio samples for an app I'm building. To play the sounds, my javascript file works like this:

1. import the WAV file
2. encode it in an array buffer
3. turn that array buffer into an audio buffer
4. create an audio context, then use that to create an audio buffer source node (ABSN).
5. store the audio buffer in the ABSN and call ABSN.start().

It feels inefficient to do steps 1-3 every time. Is there a way to do them once but then store the audio buffers in an external file and just import that next time?

Comment: Steps 1 to 3 load a file from disk and make it playable (in memory). You would have to still do them if you stored a raw binary file instead :) WAV is also not compressed so it loads very quickly and is pretty similar to a list of raw samples anyway.

Comment: @LukeBriggs so you're saying this is already the fastest workflow I can do?

Comment: Please explain the use case a little bit closer. What do you mean by "to do steps 1-3 every time"? Every time you play the sound? Every time you reopen the browser? Do you want user interaction to export and import the sound? Or do you think of some caching behind the scenes? How long should the cache persist?

Comment: @Markus Sorry I wasn't more specific. What I mean is that rather than importing a WAV file into my app and doing steps 2-3 to convert it into an audio buffer (AB), I'd like to have a directory of ABs from which my app can import and immediately use. 

Since I never use the WAV files directly, just as converted ABs, I'd rather just store the ABs themselves.

What I'm wondering is: Can I convert a WAV file into an AB and save that AB in another directory that persists after my JS ends? 

Where I'm stuck: I don't know how to persistently store a new AB after my JS program ends.

Comment: Do you think of using `IndexedDB` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API))?

Comment: What you want is not possible.  But you can simplify things a little by directly loading the WAV file into an `AudioBuffer` via `decodeAudioData`